# Is this a valid code for factory method pattern please verify

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Code below is for factory method pattern I would like it to be verified. if not valid then what are the changes that need to be made.
 here i have added both client code from where the pattern is made use and the code for implementation of pattern.

the example i have used here is of TV remote which acts as factory and returns me TV channel object based on the channel number.

client code

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  ITVChannelNew channelNew;
  channelNew = RemoteNew.getChannel(1);
  currentProgram = channelNew.getCurrentShow();
  channelNew = RemoteNew.getChannel(2);
  currentProgram = channelNew.getCurrentShow(); 
}
```

Factory method code

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
  public interface ITVChannelNew
  {
    string getCurrentShow();
    string getNextShow();
    string getPreviousShow();
  }

  public class TVChannelNew : ITVChannelNew
  {
    private readonly string previous;
    private readonly string current;
    private readonly string next;

    public TVChannelNew(string previous, string current, string next)
    {
      this.previous = previous;
      this.current = current;
      this.next = next;
    }

    public string getCurrentShow()
    {
      return current;
    }

    public string getNextShow()
    {
     return next;
    }

    public string getPreviousShow()
   {
     return previous;
    }
  }

  public class BBCNew : TVChannelNew
  {
    public BBCNew():base("BBC previous","BBC current","BB next")
    {
    }    
  }

  public class TimesNowNew : TVChannelNew
  {
    public TimesNowNew()
      : base("TimesNow previous", "TimesNow current", "TimesNow next")
    {
    } 
  }

  public static class RemoteNew
  {
    public static ITVChannelNew getChannel(int ChannelNumber)
    {
     switch (ChannelNumber)
      {
        case 1:
          return new BBCNew();
        case 2:
          return new TimesNowNew();
        default:
          return new TimesNowNew();
      }
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Not posting my own answer as I'm not an expert on the Factory Method pattern. However, I think the code is an example of the Factory pattern not Factory Method pattern.

Comment: Andy I see there is nothing like factory pattern. their is either factory method pattern or Abstract Factory pattern.

Comment: Should be moved to [codereview.se]

Comment: Abstract Factory pattern is just a longer name for Factory pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that looks good to me.

But for me I would want to have a clearer indication of what type I would expect on the client level. To do this I would define a enum somewhere such as:

```
public enum TVChannels
    {
        BBCNew,
        TimesNowNew
    }
```

And define the Factory like:

```
public static class RemoteNew
  {
    public static ITVChannelNew getChannel(TVChannels channel)
    {
            switch (channel)
            {
                case TVChannels.BBCNew:
                    break;
                case TVChannels.TimesNowNew:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
    }
}
```

This way you have clearer indication what type you want to return and also still leaves the client without knowing any of the concrete types, such as:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ITVChannelNew channelNew;
   channelNew = RemoteNew.getChannel(TVChannels.BBCNew);
   currentProgram = channelNew.getCurrentShow();
   channelNew = RemoteNew.getChannel(TVChannels.TimesNowNew);
   currentProgram = channelNew.getCurrentShow(); 
}
```

Also, if someone changed the numbers around in your factory (in the switch statement), it is not immediately clear that it is wrong. If he did spot something wrong he/she will have to ask 'what is channel 45 again?' or 'what is channel 3 meant to return?' and probably have to check some other source to check the correct values.

If you use the enumerations and someone swapped it around accidentally, the next person will stand a better chance in spotting a mistake due to the obvious wording.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the factory looks fine too me, I would perhaps call the factory TVChannelNewFactory but otherwise it seems fine.